# Обработать данные retrofit и передать адаптеру

Tags: java, json, retrofit, gson

Добрый день. Никак не могу разобраться есть rest сервис. который отдает два json
Первый

```
{
"value": [{
"Ref_Key": "011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618",
"Description": "ТЦ Бачурин",
},{
"Ref_Key": "7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"Description": "На Льва Толстого",
}]
}
```

Второй

```
    {
    "odata.metadata": "http://37.8.146.88/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Collection(StandardODATA.AccumulationRegister_ТоварыНаСкладах_Balance)",
    "value": [
    {
    "Склад_Key": "011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618",
    "Номенклатура_Key": "bb112bd5-e7b4-11e7-a2a9-3085a93c0618",
    "КоличествоBalance": 2
    },
    {
    "Склад_Key": "7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
    "Номенклатура_Key": "bb112bd5-e7b4-11e7-a2a9-3085a93c0618",
    "КоличествоBalance": 5
    }
    ]

}
```

для них есть POJO

Goods.java

```
public class Goods{
    @SerializedName("odata.metadata")
    @Expose
    private String odataMetadata;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private List<Value> value = null;

    public String getOdataMetadata() {
        return odataMetadata;
    }

    public void setOdataMetadata(String odataMetadata) {
        this.odataMetadata = odataMetadata;
    }

    public List<Value> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

CatalogWarehouses.java

```
public class CatalogWarehouses {

    @SerializedName("Description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("Ref_Key")
    @Expose
    private String refKey;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRefKey() {
        return refKey;
    }

    public void setRefKey(String refKey) {
        this.refKey = refKey;
    }

}
```

Value.java

```
public class Value {

    @SerializedName("Ref_Key")
    @Expose
    private String refKey;
    @SerializedName("Description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("Склад_Key")
    @Expose
    private String stockKey;
    @SerializedName("Номенклатура_Key")
    @Expose
    private String nomenclatureKey;
    @SerializedName("КоличествоBalance")
    @Expose
    private String amountBalance;

    public String getRefKey() {
        return refKey;
    }

    public void setRefKey(String refKey) {
        this.refKey = refKey;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getNomenclatureKey() {
        return nomenclatureKey;
    }

    public void setNomenclatureKey(String nomenclatureKey) {
        this.nomenclatureKey = nomenclatureKey;
    }



    public String getAmountBalance() {
        return amountBalance;
    }

    public void setAmountBalance(String amountBalance) {
        this.amountBalance = amountBalance;
    }

}
```

С помощью Retrofit получаю данные об остатках(Goods.java второй Json) и передаю их адаптеру. Вопрос как сделать так что бы перед передачей в адаптер добавились еще данные а именно наименования складов(CatalogWarehouses.java первый Json).
поля Ref_Key и Склад_Key в обоях Json имеют одинаковое значение.

```
ServisAPI api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
        Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> accumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehousesCall = api.getAllProducts(guid);
        accumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehousesCall.enqueue(new Callback<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> call, Response<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> response) {
               valueList = response.body().getValue;

               adapter = new CatalogNomenclatureAmountAdapter(inflater, valueList);
               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Ошибка " + t);
            }
        });
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, уже не первый час голову ломаю. Но из-за нехватки опыта и знаний решение найти не могу